# COUNT() with a nested subquery

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

Can I count a column with the number of instances of a character in a particular column?

```
+---+---+
| i | p |
+---+---+
| A | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 0 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 3 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 0 |  
| C | 0 |
+---+---+
```

Query:

```
SELECT i, SUM(p) AS Sp, COUNT(p) AS Cp FROM table   
GROUP BY i
```

Id like to get this:

```
+---+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
| i | Sp | Cp | x3x | x1x | x0x |
+---+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
| A |  5 |  3 |  1  |  2  |  0  |
| B |  4 |  3 |  1  |  1  |  0  |
| C |  4 |  3 |  1  |  0  |  2  |
+---+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Essentially I want to COUNT the instances of 3, 0 or 1 in a column where the column is grouped by the id 'i'

I tried this as well as a number of variations, but I can't seem to get it going.
`COUNT(P WHERE p='3')`, `COUNT(P WHERE p='1')`, `COUNT(P WHERE p='0')`,

Is there a means by which I can place a subquery within a COUNT() that I've missed in my research?

I also tried

`COUNT(Points='3')`, `COUNT(='1')`, `COUNT(Points='0')`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close:

```
select i, sum(points), count(*),
       sum(Points = 3), sum(points = 1), sum(Points = 0)
from t
group by i;
```

One minor difference in this case is that a removed the single quotes around the values.  When comparing to a number, don't use single quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

The more important change is from `count()` to `sum()`.  `count()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  Well, the boolean expression is true or false -- but not really `NULL` (unless `points` is `NULL`, which is not the case with your data).

MySQL treats boolean values as integers in a numeric context, with 0 for false and 1 for true.  So, adding them up counts the number of times that something is true.

Comment: So close at yet so far away this works, thank you. My logic was COUNT but if I was to anglicise the above would it be SUM the number of instances where (Points = 3), etc is true?

Comment: Cool thank you. I think I need to change the title of the question.